# Searchanise giving Randomly errors

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi I am using searchanise extension for searching in my **magento 1.9** site. But I am getting below error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SearchForm' of undefined.

On first load it works fine but after reload it shows the above error.Let me know what I am missing.

And In the admin panel
Cannot read extend property of undefined.

```
SNIZE_LOADER.loadScript(SNIZE.current_location + '/lib/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js', function() {

SNIZE.$.extend(SNIZE, { 
    index_script: 'admin.php',
    changes_warning: 'N',
    lang: {
        type_your_search_h
```

Can anyone please help me how can i debug and solve this issue.THANKS.

Comment: I found that there is some cache issue with extension files.Can i do something to files to not save in cache

Comment: Can I disable cache for a single module in magento 1.9